# Combining prisms when extracting JSON fields with lens-aeson

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson, lenses

I have a JSON blob similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "version": 1
  },
  {
    "version": "3"
  },
  ...
]
```

Note that some of the versions are numbers and some are strings.
I want to get a list of versions.
I can use the following lens combination to extract the numeric versions:

```
v1 :: [String]
v1 = obj ^.. AL.values . AL.key fieldName . AL._Number . to show
```

And the following to extract the strings

```
v2 :: [String]
v2 = obj ^.. AL.values . AL.key fieldName . AL._String . to T.unpack
```

But, how can I get a list of versions by a single pass over the list?
Is there any lens combinator that takes lenses `AL._Number . to show` and `AL._String . to T.unpack` and returns a combined getter so that if the first one failes, tries the second one? Something like `msum` for lenses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is in fact a combinator that tries an optic and goes to a backup if the first one fails.  It's called [failing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:failing).

Note that the condition on it should be satisfied by the case you describe.  Even if it wasn't, the combinator would still function, it would just behave irregularly when refactoring.  (Which is the main problem with using [filtered](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:filtered) as a `Traversal`.)

Comment: Nice. I suspected the answer would be in `Control.Lens.Traversal`, but my eyes went past this combinator amidst all the other ones :)

Comment: @duplode I totally understand.  There is a *lot* in there.

Answer (score 0):

Before [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054686/2751851), which is what you should use, I was going to suggest [`outside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:outside) as a way to perform case analysis with those prisms:

```
tryNumberThenString :: AL.AsPrimitive t => t -> [String]
tryNumberThenString =
    outside AL._Number .~ (:[]) . show $
    outside AL._String .~ (:[]) . T.unpack $
    const []
```

```
v1 = obj ^.. AL.values . AL.key fieldName . folding tryNumberThenString
```

Note that, unless there is some other trick I am missing, this is not only more complicated than what Carl suggests but also less flexible -- I can only get a `Fold` from the plain function `tryNumberThenString`, while `failing` combines the prisms into a `Traversal`.